# nifi-1.0.0 blocks when merging files

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a flow in which I process csv files (max file size ~700 mB).
I split this files in flowfiles of 1 line, then I am doing some processing and finally I use [Extended]MergeContent processor as a synchronization mechanism.
The thing is that if I process each csv file, when they are in the MergeContent's queue, it will block the nifi instance.

It blocks when I have over 1.5 million files.

Nifi is running on a server (32 cores, ~200 GB of RAM). Nifi heap size 64 or 128 same problem occurs.

Any idea why this is happening ?

If I process 5 csv files which are small, there's no problem, the processor works ok.

The [Extended]MergeContent is a processor that inherits MergeContent and it waits for all the files to bundle and then sends a signal over to the next processor. It does not compose back the whole file.
For example if my CSV file is composed out of 1 000 000 flowfiles of 1 line, then the [Extended]MergeContent will send only 1 out of 1 000 000 flowfiles, as a signal to the next processor.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your scenario -- instead of actually merging multiple flowfiles back into a single flowfile, this new "EMC" processor just waits for all the flowfiles to complete, but then only sends one (arbitrary) flowfile to the follow-on component? There is an open [Apache Jira - NIFI-1926](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-1926) for a general purpose aggregator component and a [patch](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-2590) that may accomplish what you need.

Comment: If it is blocking due to a high volume of flowfiles, you should check how this processor respects the `Yield Duration` and `Scheduling Strategy` configuration options. If this processor doesn't actually perform any logic other than waiting for `x` flowfiles, it should probably have a `Scheduling Strategy` of `Event Driven` so it's not running unnecessarily. 

You might have better luck using an `ExecuteScript` processor which just evaluates the count of received flowfiles and sleeps until it hits a configured threshold.

Comment: yes, that's exactly what it does.

Comment: If I will add the EventDriven Scheduling Strategy, I think that as soon as the first flowfile comes in, the processor will run and same thing will happen.

Comment: My case is the following:
I decompose a big csv file in 1 line flowfiles, I convert them to sql and eventually insert them in a db. After this part I have the EMC processor which is used as a synchronisation mechanism, in order to know when I have finished to process the whole CSV file. (inserted all the data into the db).

Comment: I've modified the Yield Duration, but without success.

Answer (score 0):

I've been dealing with a similar situation and struggled the same way trying to work with NiFi at that granularity level with that many files.

In my particular case, this was putting too much pressure on the garbage collector, no matter how much RAM I had underneath, or how much time I spent on GC tuning, G1 was triggering full GCs periodically. You can check if this is a garbage collector related issue looking at the summary section in the top right corner, and then system diagnostics to display gc stats.

I can suggest you to re-design your flow and batch lines together, so that you will end up with less flowfiles. Another option would be to limit the number of flowfiles in the flow at any moment in time applying back-pressure on the queues, but since you are using EMC processor as synchronization mechanism I do not know if that's possible.

Hope this helped

Comment: Thank you very much ! I've eliminated EMC, I've wrote another processor that does far less work than EMC.